# How are the objects distributed across buckets in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

What will happen if I return -1 in the hashcode method?

what will be the bucket location for negative hashcodes? Where entry of the map will be stored for the nagative hashcode?

Why doesn't it cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: @xenteros Hi, thank you very much for the detailed answer but I am still trying to understand how ` tab[(n - 1) & hash] `(bucket location) will be calculated for the -ve hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that the OP understands how `HashMap` works and the question is just about the technical details. Very often, people explain the process of distributing values across buckets to simply take a `mod` of the hash to determine the index of the bucket for an object.

This becomes problematic, when you have a negative `hash`:

```
(hash < 0 && n > 0 ) => hash % n < 0
```

To answer this question about the implementation detail in Java, let's jump directly to the source code:

```
final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
            do {
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    return e;
            } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The 'address' of an item is:

```
tab[(n - 1) & hash]
```

Where `n` is the number of buckets. This will always result in a number in range `[0, n-1]`.

According to the request for clarification in the comment section, let me explain how `&` operand work:

Let's take `n = 10` and `hash = -1`

```
       n = 00001010
    hash = 11111111
n & hash = 00001010
```

`&` is a `bitwise and` operator. It means that, for each bit it checks if it's on in both arguments.

As n is always non-negative, it'll have some leading `0s` in their IEEE-754 representation.

It means, that the result of an `&` operation will have at least the same number of leading zeros and therefor is less or equal to n.